# A problem in the tableview section headview with hitTest method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

I custom a lightGray view. The lightGray view has a property button. The button's backgroundColor is red.

I overwrite the  `hitTest` method in lightGray view.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        if (!self.isUserInteractionEnabled || self.isHidden || self.alpha <= 0.01) {
            return nil;
        }

        if([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]){
             return self.testButton;
        }

        return nil;

    }
```

As a result, the cursor at the point in the image above. I click the button could response.

[image]

If I click in the left area of lightGray view. The red button couldn't response.

What's the reason?

My real problem is the same problem in the tableview section headview. I write this demo to test and ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this behaviour even not using a table view, just a custom view, and it really looks strange - if we return button from hitTest, button's action gets fired not at whole area of the gray view, but rather only at some distance around the button.

I added a test view with a tap gesture recognizer looking for difference with button behaviour and it works as expected. So as a workaround you may replace the button with a view plus gesture recognizer.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.isUserInteractionEnabled || self.isHidden || self.alpha <= 0.01) {
        return nil;
    }

//    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, point)) {
//        return self.testButton; // fires only at some distance
//    }

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, point)) {
        return self.testView; // fires for every point inside gray view
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

- (IBAction)testButtonTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"BTN HIT"); // Not OK
}

- (IBAction)testViewTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"VIEW TAP"); // OK
}
```